# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object NotificationsRegistrationHandler only supports OFFLINE but is being called via RemoteApplicationServer

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, genexus, genexus-sd

I´m getting this error when procedure NotificationsRegistrationHandler is executed at application startup.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object NotificationsRegistrationHandler only supports OFFLINE but is being called via RemoteApplicationServer
```

As documentation says:

> If you have a completely offline application and you need this Registration Handler procedure to be generated offline exclusively, set Main property = False and Connectivity Support property = Offline

I have set my main SD object Registration Handler property to use this procedure.

I have also set the following properties on procedure NotificationsRegistrationHandler:

[image]

What it´s wrong with my code or configuration?

Thanks,
Rogelio Arosemena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution by creating an external object on Android to return One Signal Id. The code was:

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
@Override
public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
try{
return userId;
}catch(Exception e){                    
e.printStackTrace();
return "";
}
}
});
```

Device registration on One Signal was ok on SD application. The problem was that procedure NotificationRegistrationHandler was never executed (offline or online), so we can't store DeviceToken on our table.

We will have to do the same for IOS with this code:

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();

status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rogelio,

I think that this may be an issue with offline mode. We can check it out.

In the meantime, you could set to Connectivity Support = Online and this should fix your issue.

Comment: Gonzalo,I changed Connectivity Support = Online but in this case, procedure NotificationsRegistrationHandler is not executed.

Comment: I checked this on Android Monitor. No log messages for this procedure are printed.

Comment: Rogelio, the procedure will be executed in Server Side. Thats the work around for this issue. The log will not be seen from Android Monitor. Instead on the server side.

Comment: Understood Gonzalo. Does this procedure properties must be: Main Properties=true Call Protocol=Http Soap Protocol=true, and of course Connectivity=Online ?